# How can I get all posts id from any wordpress website using Beatifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to figure out how to scrape post IDs from any wordrpess website using beautifulsoup.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

article = soup.find("article")
post_id = article["id"].split("-")[1]
print(post_id)
```

Result

```
Prints:

518551
```

This is the code I found online and I want the script to print IDs like the example shown above, but wondering how can I scrape all the IDs using the website URL?

How this can be achieved?

Thank you.

Comment: `soup.find_all`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, sorry, I forgot to mention that I am a total noob and don't know how to implement the script on my VPS server. Where should I add the URL of the website I want to scrape?

Comment: How do you initialize `html_doc` in your code? Are you using the **requests** package?

Comment: I didn't setup the script, but maybe this helps - import html
import json
import requests
import re
from slugify import slugify
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def cleatattrs(html):

Comment: Normally you should do something like `html_doc = requests.get(<your-website-url-here>)`